# Copy data across two Excel spreadsheet depending on matches

Tags: excel

I have two spreadsheets - one called **1.xlsx** and another called **2.xlsx**

On 1.xlsx I have three worksheets - the one I am interested in working with is called "Master Data Set". I also have the following columns

**UserID,Hostname1,Hostname2,Hostname3**

On **2.xlsx** I have one worksheet with the following columns

**Hostname,Login**

What I am trying to do is as follows:

If value in column **Login** in **1.xlsx** matches value in column **UserID** in **2.xlsx**

Then copy

Value **Hostname** in **1.xlsx** to **Hostname1** in **2.xlsx** for that row

If it is a second match (i.e. a second **Login** matching **UserID**)

Then copy

Value **Hostname** in **1.xlsx** to **Hostname2** in **2.xlsx** for that row

If it is a third match (i.e. a third Login matching UserID)

Then copy

Value **Hostname** in **1.xlsx** to **Hostname3** in **2.xlsx** for that row

Ignore any further matches.

How would I accomplish this in Excel?

Comment: This is probably best achieved via VBA. did you want an excel formula solution or a programatic one?

Comment: @Silenxor - Excel formula

Comment: @pnuts See L42's answer, very similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be done without VBA but it will be slow depending on your data size.
and also depending on your system.
A few thousand entry may result to significant calculation time.

**Using Array formula:**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX([1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$A,SMALL(IF([1.xlsx]Sheet1!$B:$B=$A2,ROW([1.xlsx]Sheet1!$B:$B),99^99),COLUMN(A$1))),"")
```

**IMPORTANT:** Entered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
I assumed your data in `1.xlsx` is in `Sheet1` since you didn't provide it.

So, assuming your data in `1.xlsx` is like below:

[image: 2.xlsx]

In your `2.xlsx` (again assuming your data starts in Column A) enter the formula in `B2`.

[image: 1.xlsx]

you kinda interchanged your `1.xlsx` and `2.xlsx` while you are explaining.
so i don't know which is which. 
i followed the one you wrote after `What I am trying to do is as follows:`.

**TIP:** You can improve the calculation speed of the formula by providing the exact address instead of using `$B:$B` and `$A:$A`.
Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: Thanks - I'm presuming that I will have to only type in the calculation once?

Comment: yes. only once. Just type the formula in `B2` then drag and fill the other cells.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you added Hostname1, Hostname2, Hostname3 in 2.xlsx in columns C,D,E, leaving column A as Hostname and B as Login.  Paste the following code into 2.xls cell C2 and then copy it into the remaining cells in the range.

```
=IF(OFFSET('[1.xlsx]Master Data Set'!B$1,MATCH($B2,'[1.xlsx]Master Data Set'!$A:$A,0)-1,0)=$A2,$A2,"")
```